# Regex to remove chars from phone numbers

Tags: c#, regex

We need to remove chars from phone numbers using Regex.Replace() in C#. Allowed chars are + (only the first char) and [0-9]. Anything else should be filtered.

Replacing everything non numeric works fine, but how can we allow + only on as the first char?

Our Regex:

```
[^+0-9]+
```

On this number: `+41 456-7891+23` it would remove whitespace and hyphens but not the `+` in front of 23.

Any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: What language are you writing this in? Lots of languages like Ruby have built-in methods for stripping strings of characters that don't require full regexs

Comment: Please specify the language being used.

Comment: To strip out all non-digits but leave `+` if it's the first character, could use [anchors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `^[^\d+]|\b\D+` and replace with empty. See [test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bN7uB3/1)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched characters with `\1` or `$1`.

```
^(\+)|\D
```

OR

```
^(\+)|[^\d\n]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO5zI3/1)

And don't forget to add multi-line modifier `m` while using the above regex.

**Javascript:**

```
> '+41 456-7891+23'.replace(/^(\+)|\D/g, "$1")
'+41456789123'
```

**PHP:**

```
$str = '+41 456-7891+23';
echo preg_replace('~^(\+)|\D~', '\1', $str);
```

**R**:

```
> gsub("^(\\+)|\\D", "\\1", '+41 456-7891+23')
[1] "+41456789123"
```

**C#**

```
string result = Regex.Replace('+41 456-7891+23', @"^(\+)|\D", "$1");
```

**Java**

```
System.out.println("+41 456-7891+23".replaceAll("^(\\+)|\\D", "$1"));
```

**Basic sed**

```
$ echo '+41 456-7891+23' | sed 's/^\(+\)\|[^0-9]/\1/g'
+41456789123
```

**Gnu sed**

```
$ echo '+41 456-7891+23' | sed -r 's/^(\+)|[^0-9]/\1/g'
+41456789123
```

**Ruby:**

```
> '+41 456-7891+23'.gsub(/^(\+)|\D/m, '\1')
=> "+41456789123"
```

**Python**

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=^\+).*|^[^+].*', lambda m: re.sub(r'\D', '', m.group()), '+41 456-7891+23')
'+41456789123'
>>> regex.sub(r'^(\+)|[^\n\d]', r'\1', '+41 456-7891+23')
'+41456789123'
```

**Perl**

```
$ echo '+41 456-7891+23' | perl -pe 's/^(\+)|[^\d\n]/\1/g'
+41456789123
$ echo '+41 456-7891+23' | perl -pe 's/^\+(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\d\n]/\1/g'
+41456789123
```

Comment: Impressive, but I guess Mark was only interested in C# version :)

Comment: I really appreciate the other versions! Especially the PHP one!

Answer (score -1):

This is written in React. Should be easy enough converting it to VanillaJS ;)
It replaces any non-numerical values with nothing, just keeping the number (and the + sign) :)

```
    //function that is used to set the number amount that the user wants to convert
  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    //this regex cleans any non-numerical values from the input
    let RegEx = /^(\+)|[^\d\n]/;
    const cleanedInput = e.currentTarget.value.replace(RegEx, '');

    //sets the amount the user wants to convert to the cleanedInput from the RegEx
    setConvertAmount(cleanedInput);
  };
```

Comment: The same regex appears in the accepted answer.